# Apache loading PHP module - undefined symbol: unixd_config

Tags: apache-http-server, php, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm configuring a new web server on a RedHat 6.5 and am trying to enable the `php5` module on Apache 2.4.6:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/path/to/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

- When I check `httpd.conf` with Apache, I get the following error about the `LoadModule`'s line:

  ```
  Cannot load /usr/path/to/libphp5.so into server: /usr/path/to/libphp5.so: 
  undefined symbol: unixd_config
  ```

I wonder if the problem is because I have two PHP versions installed?  The one Apache should use is the alias `php55`; what is the configuration for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following and built `libphp5.so` on my own:

```php
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
PHPIniDir "/path/to/php/lib"
```

Answer (score 3):

The Apache API changed from 2.2 to 2.4, with `unixd_config` renamed to `ap_unixd_config` (see [API changes from 2.2 to 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/developer/new_api_2_4.html)).

You need a PHP module version that is compatible with Apache 2.4, else stay with Apache 2.2.

Comment: And where can I get the good module version?

Comment: For sure the right versions is available in Red Hat packages, unfortunately I can't help you further with this (I'm always with Debian). If you install standard packages you should be allright.

Comment: @Zimm I've same issue in debian7, php 5.6 and apache2.4.10 any multiple time installed php and apache and module but still same issue. Can you tell me how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to install the following package, replacing `php55` with desired version:

```bsh
yum install rh-php55-php
```

- Software is pulled from RH Software Collection, and this package contains the module, often referred to as `mod_php`, which adds support for `php` to Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -ql apache-mod_php-7.3.17-1.mga7
  /etc/httpd/conf/modules.d/00-php-fpm.conf
  /etc/httpd/conf/modules.d/70_mod_php.conf
  /usr/lib/.build-id
  /usr/lib/.build-id/e1
  /usr/lib/.build-id/e1/a7d9b6acb73030cd6809458ba4fd2bd91b66f7
  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_php.so

head -n 1 /etc/httpd/conf/modules.d/00-php-fpm.conf 
  requires apache-mod_proxy (mod_proxy.so + mod_proxy_fcgi.so)

urpmi apache-mod_proxy
```

This is for Mageia; for other operating systems, use package manager specific to that OS.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for getting `undefined symbol: unixd_config` can be if your LoadModule name was wrong.

For example, `LoadModule was_app22_module /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so` will cause this error because `was_app22_module` has an extra `p`; it should be `was_ap22_module`.